# I want to use image.onload in $.when function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am  loading images  dynamic inside loop.I have some requirement such that 
in following code when I am loading image then and then only alert  fire and when alert 1 fires then and then only alert 2 fire.

My code is

```
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
    $.when(function(){

   var img771 = new Image();

    img771.src = imggg[i];
    img771.onload=function(){
        alert("1");
       //after image becomes loaded then and then only alert 2 fires in Done functionality.
    }


    }  ).done(function () {
        alert("2");

    });
    }
```

Comment: how can you expect anyone to help when your code is illegible and your problem is poorly described?

Comment: @Alnitak Why bother making question nice, someone will edit it for sure :)

Comment: @dfsq well it won't be me...

Answer (score 1):

To convert image loading into a (jQuery) promise, use:

```
function imageLoad(url) {
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            def.resolve(img);
        };
        img.src = url;
    });
}
```

You can then create an array of Promises for your images:

```
var promises = imggg.map(imageLoad);
```

and then pass that to `$.when`:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
     console.log("all images loaded");
});
```

Comment: actually i am not getting that **imggg**??

Comment: and how can i pass url to this function

Comment: actually i i got what is imggg but your code also not working for me.

Comment: @RamP well, to be frank, you didn't give me much to start with in your question...

Comment: I have 100 and more  images and i am first a fall write that image on canvas and then i have some functions that are i will write on canvas and after that I made image from that canvas and I have to use this function inside for loop.

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid that still makes no sense.