# How to use img.onload iside $.when function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to use `img.onload iside $.when function` I want to load image inside `$ when` and alert sequence fires  following way
`1-alert("1") 2-alert("2") 3- alert("3")`

```
function temp()
     {
       $.when(function(){
       var img=new Image();
       img.onload=function()
       {
         alert("1")
       }
      img.src=url;

      }).then(function(){  
      alert("2")
      })

    alert("3")
    }
```

Comment: There is no purpose of using `$.when()` regarding your posted code

Comment: What isn't working? Where does the variable `url` come from? Is it global or *should* it be a function argument? Which **different** approaches have you taken?

Comment: @A. Wolff I have to use $.when because i have some more code in place of alert("3") and also my code is inside the loop so i want to execute all statement one by one

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand url comes from global array and that code is inside loop

Comment: @RamP You should ask question regarding your former issue(looping async op sequentially?), not the workaround you think would fix it. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Ram P you can use $.Deferred - like this http://jsfiddle.net/a5c0ye0g/, but nit only $.when

Answer (score 0):

From the [jquery api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

> **Description:** Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent *asynchronous* events.

the word *asynchronous* here means that the function will not execute until data has been received, the chance that your alert sequence will be in order is very small unless the network time is shorter than the execution time of the following javascript.

What happens when it encounters the `$.when` function is that it allows JS to kind of *skip* this function and continue executing the script until the function receives a response from a request.

In this case the *request* comes from the *src* attribute which you set within the `$.when` - JS then continues to execute your script and notices `alert('3')` so that's what it'll do first but then when the actual image is loaded the `$.when` will fire which in turn will fire your `alert('1')` and because the connected callback `$.then` is chained onto the `$.when` the `alert('2')` will finally fire last.

You cannot construct your alerts to be in order with this construction or not **reliably** anyways.

If you want to have your `alert('1')`, `alert('2')` and `alert('3')` fired in order you could change the function to this (which will remove the need for `$.when`)

```
function temp() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        alert('1');
        alert('2');
        alert('3');
    }
    img.src = url // make sure url is set somewhere!
}
```

Since you're showing your examples with alerts instead of any real code it's hard to see what you're trying to do but doing this will wait till the image is loaded and basically spam you with alerts afterwards.

In JS it's not particularly popular to spawn alerts all over the place - they are ugly and inconsistent and for loading an image you definitely don't want to show 3 of them in any situation (unless your name is photoshop ofcourse ^.^).

Either way, hope it helps - read up on the documentation for more info on `$.when` - every serious programmer gets his knowledge from deeply understanding how a method works by reading the documentation before implementing an actual script using that function.

(ofcourse in reality this is not true, most devs just use functions and sometimes wonder why they *don't* work as expected but then there comes a time where they are sick of **not** understanding and they'll end up like the above paragraph :))

Comment: actually i am writing alert only because my code is of 500-1000 lines instead of alert and also that all code present inside for loop

Comment: Well, this is the most simple solution out there without using jQuery but I would however check the answer on your [previously posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736722/i-want-to-use-image-onload-in-when-function) question since that includes jQuery.